# How to remove gray screen before splash screen - Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Has someone managed to remove the gray screen when launching an ionic app from an android device?
Is there a way to remove this annoying gray screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution it's working fine for me using 5 steps.

**1.)** Create a file name **colors.xml** inside project\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="gray">#fff</color>
    <color name="black">#fff</color>
</resources>
```

**2.)** Then create a new file **styles.xml** inside project\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\values

```
<resources>
  <style name="SplashTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

**3.)** Then open **AndroidManifest.xml** from project\platforms\android\app\src\main, then search `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar"` and replace with `android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"`

**4.)** Create a folder name drawable inside project\platforms\android\app\src\main\res

**5.)** Inside drawable folder create a new file having name **background_splash.xml** and the code is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
    <item android:drawable="@color/black"/>   
</layer-list>
```

That's all. 
Hope its help.

Answer (score 1):

for me i added this code in style.xml file: `/Users/User/Development/project/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="SplashTheme"  parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
      <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
      <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
      <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
      <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
      <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
     <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    
</style>
</resources>
```

and edited my AndroidManifest.xml File : `android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"` added that to the activity

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

and

```
xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0"
```

( if not present) inside you widget tag in you config.xml present in the root of your project.

Then replace android:theme value of your main activity with

```
@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen
```

Thats it. You need not add any custom styles (If you don't want).