# Cordova (android) : Avoid the grey background before splash screen

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cross-platform, cordova-plugins

How to avoid the dark grey background which will flash for a second before the splash screen appears in android app built by Cordova ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple plugin for Android which will set the window background color for you app's MainActivity to a color of your choice. This allows you to avoid the standard dark grey background which will flash for a second before your splash screen appears. Set the color to the same background as your splash screen for a smoother start-up effect.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-android-window-background --variable WINDOW_BACKGROUND_COLOR=#ff69b4 --save
```

add this to your config.xml file:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-window-background">
    <variable name="WINDOW_BACKGROUND_COLOR" value="#B4D455" />
</plugin>
```

*for more info visit :*
https://github.com/winteragency/cordova-plugin-android-window-background

Comment: this works, it changed the black screen background color to white, but i'd like to remove the initial screen completely or replace it with splashscreen

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the plugin 'cordova-plugin-android-window-background' didn't work for me, it closes the application.

This solution provided by @Nsamba Isaac worked like a charm on my phone right now

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72063894/5961202